# Match string with static list of 30k strings in java

Tags: java

I have below scenario :-

String accountNum = "3456";
Static list that 30k strings like 1334,3345,7776,7788,5566....up to 30k.
If accountNum exists in 30k static list then display yes else display no.

What is the best way to handle this situation in java in terms of performance, memory ?

Comment: keep these in int(primitive), this is for memory. In order to check whether exists you will need to put these in HashSet and for that you need to keep these in Integer Object.

Comment: Instead of a `List` use a `Set` of `Integer`s that way you have O(1) access time when using `Set.contains()`

Comment: (Micro-)Optimize for memory? Make a sorted distinct `short[]` and use binary search.

Comment: @Lino -  These 30K strings may update periodically so need to store somewhere so that there won't be code change every time. Please suggest what is the best practice to store these huge strings

Comment: @RaviKukreja You should store data in some form of file. Then read this file at runtime. That way you don't have to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

convert your strings to integers and use java.util.BitSet

it is a bitwise operation, so saves memory

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BitSet bit = new BitSet(30000);

    bit.set(1122);
    bit.set(3344);
    bit.set(5566);
    //.....

    System.out.println(bit.get(1122)); //true
}
```

Comment: thanks. These 30K strings may update periodically so need to store somewhere so that there won't be code change every time. Please suggest what is the best practice to store these huge strings.